# Row Number with a mySQL Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following Query that works correctly:

```
SELECT  @row_num :=  IF(@prev_value=concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text)  ,@row_num+1, 1) AS     POSITION
   ,o.idBUSINESS
   ,o.KEYWORD_TEXT
   ,o.CITY
 , o.BID_AMOUNT
  ,@prev_value := concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text) 
FROM   (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
  (SELECT @prev_value := '') y,
  (SELECT @prev_value1 := '') z,
elevated_business_queue o
ORDER BY o.CITY , o.KEYWORD_TEXT, o.BID_AMOUNT DESC
```

This query returns:

```
# POSITION, idBUSINESS, KEYWORD_TEXT, CITY, BID_AMOUNT, @prev_value := concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text)
'1', '7', '2', 'New Jersey', '3.50', 'New Jersey2'
'2', '5', '2', 'New Jersey', '2.50', 'New Jersey2'
'3', '1', '2', 'New Jersey', '2.50', 'New Jersey2'
'1', '5', '1', 'New York', '2.50', 'New York1'
'2', '7', '1', 'New York', '2.30', 'New York1'
'3', '1', '1', 'New York', '1.50', 'New York1'
'1', '9', '2', 'New York', '7.50', 'New York2'
'2', '1', '2', 'New York', '4.50', 'New York2'
'3', '5', '2', 'New York', '3.50', 'New York2'
'4', '7', '2', 'New York', '2.50', 'New York2'
```

This data is correct. Now, I want to join the elevated_business_queue with another table. I am doing it as follows:

```
SELECT  @row_num :=  IF(@prev_value=concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text)  ,@row_num+1, 1) AS POSITION
   ,o.idBUSINESS
   ,o.KEYWORD_TEXT
   ,o.CITY
 , o.BID_AMOUNT
   ,@prev_value := concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text) 
    FROM   (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
  (SELECT @prev_value := '') y,
  (SELECT @prev_value1 := '') z,
elevated_business_queue o
INNER JOIN funds_balance fb ON fb.idBUSINESS = o.idBUSINESS
 WHERE fb.PREMIUM_POSITIONS_CREDIT >= (o.BID_AMOUNT + ROUND((12.36/100)*o.BID_AMOUNT, 2))
ORDER BY o.CITY , o.KEYWORD_TEXT, o.BID_AMOUNT DESC
```

However, when I join, my POSITION gets messed up. I am now getting:

```
# POSITION, idBUSINESS, KEYWORD_TEXT, CITY, BID_AMOUNT, @prev_value := concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text)
'2', '7', '2', 'New Jersey', '3.50', 'New Jersey2'
'1', '1', '2', 'New Jersey', '2.50', 'New Jersey2'
'1', '5', '2', 'New Jersey', '2.50', 'New Jersey2'
'2', '5', '1', 'New York', '2.50', 'New York1'
'3', '7', '1', 'New York', '2.30', 'New York1'
'1', '1', '1', 'New York', '1.50', 'New York1'
'1', '1', '2', 'New York', '4.50', 'New York2'
'2', '5', '2', 'New York', '3.50', 'New York2'
'1', '7', '2', 'New York', '2.50', 'New York2'
```

Can someone please help.

--------------UPDATE----------------------

I tried with the following query but the POSITION is still off:

```
SELECT T1.*,fb.* FROM
(SELECT  @row_num :=  IF(@prev_value=concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text)  ,@row_num+1, 1) AS       POSITION
,o.idBUSINESS
,o.KEYWORD_TEXT
,o.CITY
,o.BID_AMOUNT
,@prev_value := concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text) 
FROM   (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
 (SELECT @prev_value := '') y,
 (SELECT @prev_value1 := '') z,
elevated_business_queue o
ORDER BY o.CITY , o.KEYWORD_TEXT, o.BID_AMOUNT DESC)T1
INNER JOIN funds_balance fb ON fb.idBUSINESS = T1.idBUSINESS
WHERE fb.PREMIUM_POSITIONS_CREDIT >= (T1.BID_AMOUNT + ROUND((12.36/100)*T1.BID_AMOUNT,    2))
ORDER BY T1.CITY ,T1.KEYWORD_TEXT, T1.BID_AMOUNT DESC;
```

I now get the following result-set:

```
# POSITION, idBUSINESS, KEYWORD_TEXT, CITY, BID_AMOUNT, @prev_value := concat(o.CITY, o.keyword_text), idBUSINESS, PREMIUM_POSITIONS_CREDIT
'1', '7', '2', 'New Jersey', '3.50', 'New Jersey2', '7', '17.30'
'3', '1', '2', 'New Jersey', '2.50', 'New Jersey2', '1', '12.31'
'2', '5', '2', 'New Jersey', '2.50', 'New Jersey2', '5', '15.19'
'1', '5', '1', 'New York', '2.50', 'New York1', '5', '15.19'
'2', '7', '1', 'New York', '2.30', 'New York1', '7', '17.30'
'3', '1', '1', 'New York', '1.50', 'New York1', '1', '12.31'
'2', '1', '2', 'New York', '4.50', 'New York2', '1', '12.31'
'3', '5', '2', 'New York', '3.50', 'New York2', '5', '15.19'
'4', '7', '2', 'New York', '2.50', 'New York2', '7', '17.30'
```

There is no POSITION=1 for KEYWORD_TEXT=2 in New York. The following row should have a position of 1:

```
'2', '1', '2', 'New York', '4.50', 'New York2', '1', '12.31'
```

Comment: Ranking function is something I dont trust on any given day, I agree, logically it should work). The ordering happens after initial row fetch and by then, the variable based column might already be having set.

Comment: What is the right way to handle this situation then? Is there some strategy to deal with this reliably?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could replace your row_num calculation with a window function like this:

```
row_number() over(partition by o.CITY , o.KEYWORD_TEXT order by o.BID_AMOUNT DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you're misplacing the order by columns. If you require ordering by KEYWORD_TEXT  then by  BID_AMOUNT  and CITY (if yes then)

Change order by as:

```
 ORDER BY KEYWORD_TEXT, BID_AMOUNT  CITY
```